# Multiple ios apps share one facebook app

Tags: facebook, ios6

I followed the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/ for sharing a single FB appID across multiple iOS apps but they don't deal at all with the fact that the FB app page requires me to specify a single bundleID and that any app not matching that bundleID doesn't work.

I have messed around with Product Name, Bundle display name, and Bundle Name but not yet found a combo that does the trick.

Any clues/pointers as to how one gets different apps with different bundleID's to interact with a single Facebook App would be much appreciated. If it's even possible...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer to this is simple: Facebook allows a *list* of BundleID's despite indications to the contrary. Simply add a comma-separated list of bundle id's to your Facebook app page.